# How to get query parameters in ExceptionHandler?

Tags: exception, jsf-2, navigation

In our project (**JBoss 7.0.2**, **JSF 2**), we work on a solution to catch all exceptions during user navigation and redirect them to nice error pages.

I used an `ExceptionHandler`, inspired by a lot of [examples](http://ovaraksin.blogspot.com/2010/10/global-handling-of-all-unchecked.html) and [tutorials](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/edburns/archive/2009/09/03/dealing-gracefully-viewexpiredexception-jsf2) online.

I managed to do a redirection feature without too much difficulty: in the `ExceptionHandler.handle()` method, for some exceptions (expired view/session, unauthenticated user asking a denied page, ...) I redirect the user on the login page through a good old

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(myRedirectPage);
```

with an additional query parameter containing the original url base64 encoded, and after a successful authentication I use the same redirection mechanism to send the user back to their page.

---

The problem is with `ViewExpiredException` on JSF actions, by example when the user click after their view has expired on any button or link with action or actionListener, synchronous or ajax-style, like

```
<h:commandButton action="#{myBean.myAction}" value="do that" />
```

or

```
<h:commandLink value="do that too">
    <f:ajax render=":aZone" execute="@form" listener="#{myBean.myOtherAction}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

**I cannot manage to obtain the query parameters in my `ExceptionHandler.handle()` method.**

I tried to put my parameters in a `f:metadata` section, like

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="myParam" value="#{myBean.myParam}" />
</f:metadata>
```

and to include them in the action, so in the method bound to button action I returned

```
"myPage.xhtml?includeViewParams=true"
```

but it changed nothing :-/

Am I doing something wrong? Where am I supposed to find the query paremeters? Is it in

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()
```

** UPDATE **

As said in comments, view params are no more available after a `ViewExpiredException` (quite obvious, in fact), so params are to be stored elsewhere (@BalusC quickly suggested in a request scope or through cookie).

Answer (score 0):

The request parameters are available by [`ExternalContext#getRequestParameterMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestParameterMap%28%29).

```
Map<String, String> params = externalContext.getRequestParameterMap();
// ...
```

Or if your application uses same parameter name with multiple values (which is usually the case for `<h:selectManyXxx>` components), use [`ExternalContext#getRequestParameterValuesMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestParameterValuesMap%28%29) instead

```
Map<String, String[]> params = externalContext.getRequestParameterValuesMap();
// ...
```

Please note that this only returns the parameters of the **current** request, not of the initial request in case of postbacks.

As to the [`ExternalContext#getRequest()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequest%28%29), it returns in case of JSF applications running on a servlet container an instance of [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) which you'd need to cast, but you should rarely have the need to get it. The [`ExternalContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html), while following the Facade design pattern, has a lot of methods which are delegating to the underlying raw HTTP servlet request, session and context. You'd namely ultimately like to end up with *zero* `javax.servlet` imports in your backing beans.

---

**Update** as per your comment, you actually want to get only the view parameters which are been registered by `<f:viewParam>`. You can get them by [`ViewMetadata#getViewParameters()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/view/ViewMetadata.html#getViewParameters%28javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot%29) wherein you pass the current `UIViewRoot`.

```
Collection<UIViewParameter> viewParameters = ViewMetadata.getViewParameters(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot());
// ...
```

Comment: Is there a way to find the `viewParam` only in `ExternalContext.getRequestParameterMap()`, as this map contains all parameters if I remember well (cannot test currently)?

Comment: Uh you want only the view parameters? That's not exactly the same as query parameters... I'll update the answer.

Comment: Never heard of `ViewMetadata` in fact :) Anyway, I managed to get the viewParams from it but they are null. Perhaps, as I link my viewParam to a `ViewScoped` bean property, something like `<f:viewParam name="myParam" value="#{myViewScopedBean.myParam}"/>`, and as my code is reached _after_ a `ViewExpiredException`, maybe what I want to do is impossible? I mean, the viewParam value is stored in a viewscoped bean, but after my view expired, I probably cannot reach it anymore. Is it true? If it is, is there a way to store the viewParam value in order to still get it after a view expiration?

Comment: D'oh, that makes absolutely sense! The initial view is not available during a `ViewExpiredException`. You'd need to look for alternate ways, perhaps request or cookie based.

Comment: Well, I will look for an alternate way, this feature is not our top one priority for now. If I find something neat, I'll reply here and keep you informed.